# Cant Git Push Using Python (Subprocess)?

Tags: python, git, ssh

I have this script that is supposed to push the files in the script’s current directory to a repo:

```py
def pushToGit():
    currDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))
    try:
        shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(currDir, '.git'))
    except:
        pass
    try:
        cp = cmd.run("git init", check=True, shell=True, cwd=currDir)
        cp = cmd.run(f"git remote add origin git@github.com:johnsmith/repo_hold.git", check=True, shell=True, cwd=currDir + "//")
        cp = cmd.run("git config user.name 'john smith'", check=True, shell=True, cwd=currDir + "//")
        cp = cmd.run("git config user.email 'john@smith.com'", check=True, shell=True, cwd=currDir + "//")
        cp = cmd.run("git add .", check=True, shell=True, cwd=currDir + "//")
        message = f"Some generated message here"
        cp = cmd.run(f"git commit -m '{message}'", check=True, shell=True, cwd=currDir + "//")
        cp = cmd.run("git push -u origin master", check=True, shell=True, cwd=currDir + "//")
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        return False
```

The process is simple: just initialize the folder, add the configuration, add the files, commit with a message, and push.

In this example, I am trying to use the SSH method since this will be ran automatically, so it cannot type a password. The SSH keys are in the same folder (for the sake of example) and are attached to my GitHub account.

However, I run into the following error:

```
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:2897/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/John/Desktop/my_repo/.git/
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in id_rsa.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
error: pathspec 'URL' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: pathspec 'added'' did not match any file(s) known to git
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Sep/2020 22:13:36] "←[37mGET /<url post request here> HTTP/1.1←[0m" 200 -
```

I am not sure what is causing the problem. I don’t understand the error in the console. This is the first time I’m using the SSH method but I don’t see how I would be using it wrong.

If it helps, this is what the files look like in the directory:

[image: Directory view]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First, add some echo between your command to isolate the one which trigger the error.

Second, add a `git status` to check:

- if you are in the right working directory
- the state of the files

An error like `pathspec 'added'' did not match any file(s) known to git` seems to indicate it is trying to add or commit files using the output of a previous command.

Using [`gitpython-developers/GitPython`](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython) would be safer.